# Where is pointer metadata stored?

Tags: c++, pointers, metadata

Could be that I am overlooking something obvious, but where is pointer metadata stored? For instance if I have a 32-bit int pointer `ptr` and I execute `ptr++` it knows to advance 4 bytes in memory. However, if I have a 64-bit int pointer it knows to advance 8 bytes. So who keeps track of what type of pointer `ptr` is and where is it stored? For simplicity you can limit this to C++.

Comment: Short answer: magic.  Long answer, it need not be stored anywhere, because the compiler can do the requested pointer arithmetic at compile-time.

Comment: Alok, you should post that as an answer. It is excellent.

Comment: From the FAQ *'No question is too trivial or too "newbie".'*, so the [n00b] tag is unnecessary and in any case, misspelled.

Comment: Erm, I figured there was a reason this was the only n00b tag. I'm curious why you considered it misspelled however.

Comment: Aside from a few (and I do mean few) usernames, you won't find much leetspeak around here. The culture run rather more to conscientiously professional programmers and students who plan to be.

Comment: Ha, ok, well ignoring the level of professionalism here, I stand by n00b being a word, properly spelled at that. Sorry to hear I can't have joke tags, but thank you for your response.

Comment: Have it your way. You'll fine more frivolity on meta.

Comment: I feel like a n00b at not having answered the question :-P.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It isn't stored anywhere, per-se. The compiler looks at the type of the ptr and turns the ++ operation into an increment of the correct number of bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even consider that it could be computed at compile time.

Answer (score 8):

In the [symbol table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) while the compiler runs. Nowhere while *your* program runs, or rather it is implicit in the lower level code produced by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It's not stored anywhere, it's determined at compile time. In fact, take this code as an example:

```
int *abc = NULL;
cout << abc + 1; /* Prints sizeof(int) */
cout << (void *)((char *)abc + 1); /* Prints 1. Casting it back to void * is necessary,
           otherwise it will try to dereference it and print as a string. */
```